# How does continuity affect limits?

Tags: calculus, limits

Let $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$; given that $f(x)$ is not continuous, does this mean that $\lim_{x\to0}f(x) ≠ f(\lim_{x\to0}x)$? And if so, why is that?

Comment: Note that $f(0)$ is undefined, so the equality is doomed from the start (since the RHS is undefined). In fact. the LHS also doesn't exist, so it's "double-doomed". Also, as Henno Brandma's answer indicates, $f$ is, in fact, continuous on its domain.

Comment: @joshuaheckroodt I feel you are a little bit confused by the answers that have been given so far. Both are perfectly OK but if you just started on math, you will be in need of some closer guidance. For that, we need to know what you understand and what you don't understand yet.

Answer (score 2):

$f(x)$ **is** continuous on $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$, its domain.

You just cannot extend it to a continuous function on all of $\mathbb{R}$ because $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)$ does not exist, so there is no candidate value for $x=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Continuity of $f$ at $a$ requires that both $f(a)$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x)$ exist, and, if they indeed exist, that they are equal.

If they don't both exists, the first condition is not satisfied, so the logical "AND" of the two conditions cannot be satisfied, regardless of whether or not the second condition is satisfied.

Amusingly, note that if one or the other fails to exist, then the second condition is actually true (because "if FALSE then X" is always true, regardless of what X is), though the overal condition is false (being "FALSE and TRUE"). The test condition is of the form
$$(\textrm{EXIST}) \textrm{ and }(\textrm{EXIST}\implies \textrm{EQUALITY})$$

To fend off objections, note that I'm not saying equality is satisfied here. I'm saying that "existence implies equality" is satisfied, since "existence" is false.